# Are people of African descent subject to more harassment in Finland than other EU countries?

Tags: europe, racism

[Helsinki times](https://www.helsinkitimes.fi/finland/finland-news/domestic/24376-study-finland-is-perceived-as-one-of-the-most-racist-countries-in-eu.html) ([Largest newspaper in the country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helsinki_Times)) writes:

> PEOPLE of African descent consider Finland as one of the most racist countries in the European Union, suggests a 13-member state study by the EU Agency for Fundamental Rights (FRA).
>
> In Finland, 43 per cent of such people reported to having experienced racial harassment in the past year, a proportion that is higher than in any of the other 12 countries: Austria, Belgium, Denmark, France, Germany, Ireland, Italy, Luxembourg, Poland, Portugal, Spain and Sweden.
>
> The proportion rose to 52 per cent when respondents were asked if they have experienced racial harassment in the past five years.
>
> Experiences of racial harassment from the past year were nearly as common in Germany (42%) and the least common in Portugal (6%) and Sweden (10%). On average, 24 per cent of respondents across the member states stated that they have experienced racial harassment in the past year and 30 per cent in the past five years.

- Are people of African descent subject to more harassment in Finland than other EU countries?
- if so, is there indication why?

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is a link to [the actual survey](https://fra.europa.eu/en/news/2023/black-people-eu-face-ever-more-racism) in the article that says

> Racist harassment
>
> > Nearly one in three respondents of African descent (30 %) say that they
> > experienced racist harassment in the 5 years before the survey. There are
> > considerable variations between EU Member States, ranging from 54 %
> > of respondents in Germany and 52 % of respondents in Finland to 10 %
> > of respondents in Portugal.
> >
> > > One in four respondents (23 %) who are parents or guardians say that their
> > > children experienced racist harassment/bullying at school. The highest
> > > rates are in Austria, Finland, Germany and Ireland, at almost 40 %. 8 %
> > > of parents/guardians say that their children experienced racist violence
> > > at school, with the highest levels in Ireland (23 %) and Finland (20 %)

[Amnesty brings more sources](https://www.amnesty.fi/finland-must-dismantle-structural-racism-now/) with some possible explanations to the "why".

Note that [Finland discriminates minorities](https://helda.helsinki.fi/server/api/core/bitstreams/3e1e41e8-fedf-4bd7-884b-963ea2bcb3e6/content) in [general](https://julkaisut.valtioneuvosto.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/162843/OM_2021_7_SO.pdf?sequence=4&isAllowed=y), and that Finland is a relatively [low immigration country](https://www.indexmundi.com/finland/demographics_profile.html#:%7E:text=Finnish%20(official)%2086.9%25%2C,6.4%25%20(2020%20est.)&text=The%20World%20Factbook%2C%20the%20indispensable%20source%20for%20basic%20information.&text=Lutheran%2067.8%25%2C%20Greek%20Orthodox%201.1,29.4%25%20(2020%20est.)):

> Finnish (official) 86.9%, Swedish (official) 5.2%, Russian 1.5%, other 6.4% (2020 est.)

that has [relatively few](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Finland#Country_of_birth) "Black people" as the survey calls them.